# RDLC Proportional Image Alignment

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, alignment, rdlc

In a RDLC file, is there any way to align an image to the center of a Tablix cell height? Somehow, it can only have a fixed location. The only solution I can find would be the padding, but I can't seem to find a way to get the cell dimension at runtime.

The reason I need to do this is because other cell on the row might change the height of the row, and since it's mostly just textboxes, the image looks do not align.

Comment: In my 5+ years of RDLC experience I think this cannot be done. Will have to make do with `Fit proportion` or miss aligned image.

Comment: @HardcoreGamer i actually found a solution, will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some kind of solution. It requieres to know the value of the field that will affect the height of the line. **You also need a monospaced font.**
So basically, I set an expression for the padding of the image. From there i call a report function:

```
Function GetLineAmount(ByVal str As String, ByVal lineLength As Integer) As Integer
    Dim amount As Integer = 1
    
    If str.Length > lineLength Then
        Dim positionToFind As Integer = lineLength
        
        If str(positionToFind) <> " " Then
            ' Find the last position of a space character
            Do While positionToFind >= 0 AndAlso str(positionToFind) <> " "
                positionToFind -= 1
            Loop
            
            ' Find the last position before that which is not a space (group of spaces)
            Do While positionToFind >= 0 AndAlso str(positionToFind) = " "
                positionToFind -= 1
            Loop
            
            positionToFind += 1
            
        End If
        
        If positionToFind = 0 Then 
            positionToFind = lineLength
        End If
        
        Dim rest As String = str.Substring(positionToFind)

        'PDF somehow "deletes" the first space in a line of text, so 2 space will leave one ... leaving this if to adapt to the pdf.
        If rest.Length > 0 AndAlso rest(0) = " " Then
            rest = rest.Substring(1)
        End If
        
        If rest <> String.Empty Then
            amount += GetLineAmount(rest, lineLength)
        End If
    End If
    
    Return amount
End Function
```

This will return the number of line a field will take. You must know the number of character a line will take (**which is why you need a monospaced font**)

Then from the image padding expression, the code will be :

```
 =  iif(Code.GetLineAmount(Fields!Description.Value,24) = 1
    , "1pt"
    , (4 + (6 * (Code.GetLineAmount(Fields!Description.Value,24) -2) )) & "pt"
    )
```

So in that part i send the field *Description* which is the one taking more line sometime, then the 24, the number of caracters that can fit the lines.

***(This part is to explain the if)*** From my test, those were the observation for the padding on top and bottom:

- 1 line would need a 1pt padding
- 2 line needed 4 pt
- 3 and more were increment of 6.